# Wrong label at the chart

Tags: machine-learning

The line on the Label is not what I want, because one is a show box and one is a show line

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,5), dpi=100)
sns.histplot(x='hour_created', data=training1_data, hue='bot', alpha=.25, 
             kde=True, stat='density', common_bins=True, element='step', legend=True)

plt.legend(title='Account Type', loc='best', labels=['Bot', 'Human'])
plt.title("Time of Day Account was Created", fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Time of Day (24h)', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Density', fontsize=10)
plt.xlim(0, 24)
plt.ylim(0, 0.05)
sns.despine();
#plt.savefig('imgs/hour_created.png');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpjim.png)

What I want is for bot and human show to be line and different colors